# Как изменить значение во всех связанных таблицах

Tags: mysql

Есть две таблицы groups и students,

```
groups
id | name  | 
1  | BB-31 | 
2  | BB-32 |
3  | PR-41 |  

students
id | group |
1  | BB-31 | 
2  | PR-41 |
```

На `groups.name` и `students.group` весит `forgeign key`. Как сделать что-бы при изменении данных в `groups.name` они же сразу менялись в `students.group`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень неправильно вешать связь между таблицам на изменяемое поле вроде **name**. Обычно в каждую таблицу добавляют так называемый *суррогатный ключ*, то самое поле **id** типа `INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`.

По меньшей мере это решение избавит вас от необходимости одновременного изменения полей в связанных таблицах.

Но, если такое изменение всё-таки нужно, используйте внешние ключи с опцией *каскадного обновления*.

Объявляя таблицу `students`, опишите *внешний ключ*:

```sql
CREATE TABLE students
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `group` NOT NULL VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARI KEY (id),
    FOREIGH KEY (`group`) REFERENCES groups (name) ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Мы заключаем название поля `group` в обратные апострофы, потому что оно совпадает с началом ключевого слова `GROUP BY`.

Теперь, при изменении поля `groups.name` будет меняться поле `students.group` у всех студентов из данной группы.

Детали: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html